# Comparing the coefficients of groups in a logistic regression

Tags: python, logistic-regression, statsmodels, anova, coefficients

My data looks like this:

```
patent  combination  breakthrough  patent_citations  science_citations
1           a            1               12                 5
2           b            1               14                 4
3           c            0               50                 6
4           ab           0               11                 4
5           ac           0               2                  1
6           bc           1               3                  14
```

Where 'combination' is categorical, 'breakthrough' is binary, the last two variables are continuous.

In Python, let's say. I get the following output using logistic regression in statsmodels:

```
                        coef   std_err     z      P>|z|  [0.025    0.975]
intercept              -3.15     0.605    -5.05   0.00  -4.2     -1.9
combination[b]          1.12     0.105    -6.05   0.00   1.2      1.9
combination[c]          1.14     0.205    -6.05   0.00   1.2      1.5
combination[ab]         2.51     0.305    -7.05   0.00   2.2      3.9
combination[ac]         3.51     0.505    -4.05   0.00   3.2      4.9
combination[bc]         3.81     0.705    -4.05   0.00   3.2      3.9
patent_citations        0.11     0.005     6.05   0.00   0.1      1.9
science_citations       0.05     0.004     3.05   0.00   0        0.9
```

Where 'breakthrough' is a dependent variable, combination[a] is the reference group.

After this regression I want to a test to check whether groups are different from each other. I do not want to run ANOVA and post-hoc test (Tukey HSD), because these tests will compare mean differences by ignoring my control variables (i.e. patent_citations, science_citations). In other words, I aim at checking whether the slopes of the regression coefficients are statistically different from each other.

Comment: you can use wald test methods of results instances, `wald_test`, `wald_test_terms` and `t_test_pairwise` for statistical significance of regression coefficients.

Comment: thank you for your advice. I think it works. Just a question: let's in the regression one coef is significant, another is not. Can we look at their combination in the wald test? or do we focus on combinations if both of them are significant in the regression?

Comment: When we have many coefficients, then we have to take multiple testing into account, e.g. use some pvalue corrections similar to what tukey-hsd does. Often we do the reversed of your last question: we test the joint hypthesis for several coefficients first, and only look at individual tests if the joint hypothesis for no effect is rejected.

Comment: I think I need to interpret the pairwise test in the end, because I am interested if two coefficients in the regression are significantly different. If at least one coef is insignificant in the regression, then by default its combination with any "group" will be insignificant in the pairwise test? Or in the regression one group is significant compared to the reference group. Then their combination in the pairwise test will be significant too?

Comment: pairwise is just a collection of individual t-tests. So the pvalues will be the same as when testing one of the pairs individually. However, when we add multiple testing pvalue corrections, then the pvalues will increase and some tests may not be significant anymore.